# vimrc settings apply not at start but only after sourcing

Tags: vim, settings

I have those lines in my vimrc file :

```
set concealcursor=n
set conceallevel=3
hi AsteriskBold ctermfg=Green cterm=bold
syn match Asterisks contained "**" conceal
syn match AsteriskBold "\*\*[^*]\+\*\*" contains=Asterisks
```

they apply if I open a new file in vim, but if I open an already existing file it doesn't work before I run :source ~/.vimrc

the other settings however applys properly, I don't have to source them :

```
set directory=~/.vim/swapfiles//
colo torte
set tabstop=2
set autoindent
set number
```

I don't understand why? I suppose they are overwritten by other vim settings, but not if it's a new file, and I don't know how to find where are the settings overridden them?

for exemple if I run

`touch test.txt`

`echo hello > test.txt`

`echo \*\*world\*\* >> test.txt`

`vim test.txt`

I obtain

> 1 hello
>
> 2 * * world * *
>
> ~
>
> ~
>
> ~

now if I run `:verbose set conceallevel` it output `conceallevel=3` `last modification in ~/.vimrc`

if then I run `:source ~/.vimrc` I obtain

> 1 hello
>
> 2 **world**
>
> ~
>
> ~
>
> ~

and if I run again `:verbose set conceallevel` it still output `conceallevel=3` `last modification in ~/.vimrc`

all of that is done on .txt files, but if I try on .js files it works exactly the same. however, my settings doesn't seems to apply on a .html file, but I don't care

Comment: Could you update your question with a) the filetype(s) with which you have seen this behaviour?, b) a minimal example of a file where you see this behaviour? I think I understand your problem but cannot be sure without that extra information.

Comment: probably there is a plugin which overwrites your settings, what is the output of `:verbose set conceallevel?`

Comment: wow, I don't what I was thinking yesterday, but I got it really wrong... I don't understund what made me think some settings worked and other didn't, none of them actually work before I source them, so it's a different problem, i'm sorry. The title remain true so I will just edit my message to fit the reality and apology again !

Comment: ho.. I know what happend, it's an additionnal problem, since yesterday I moved my ~/.vimrc file to ~/.vim/.vimrc, I thought this directory was checked by vim at the opening as well, I'll put it back to the first place, check if the problem is as I described it, modifiy my post with your questions, and tell you when it's done

Comment: ok if we forget my mistake with the displacement of the .vimrc file, the problem looks exactly as described first, and I added the informations you asked

Comment: @flemingfleming file type .txt and exemple above :)

Comment: @Doktor OSwaldo result of verbose doesn't help me since I thought it would have change before and after sourcing... but it doesn't !

Comment: so `conceallevel` seems not to change what about the other stuff, try `verbose hi AsteriskBold` f. e.

Comment: `:verbose hi AsteriskBold` gives me `AsteriskBold   xxx cleared`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your highlight group `AsteriskBold` is being cleared out by your  color scheme (to confirm this enter the command `:hi AsterisksBold`). For instance, from the first few lines of `default` color scheme (located in `:e $VIMRUNTIME/color/default.vim`):

```
" Remove all existing highlighting and set the defaults.
hi clear
```

This will clear existing highlighting groups including `AsteriskBold`. A possible solution is to trigger your highlighting settings with auto commands:

```
autocmd ColorScheme * hi AsteriskBold ctermfg=Green cterm=bold                     
autocmd BufEnter * syn match Asterisks contained "**" conceal                   
autocmd BufEnter * syn match AsteriskBold "\*\*[^*]\+\*\*" contains=Asterisks
```

Comment: it's much better ! the conceal action now works great, but the coloration is still cleared as it says when i run `:verbose hi AsteriskBold`

Comment: has anyone an idea why the conceal action work but not the highlight action ?

Comment: I mark this answer as the solution because it almost was, I just had to modify a tiny thing, and honestly I don't know why and would be happy if someone could explain ! modification is not putting the highlight command line in autocommand

Answer (score 3):

finally what works was this :

```
set concealcursor=n
set conceallevel=3
hi AsteriskBold ctermfg=Green cterm=bold
autocmd BufEnter * syn match Asterisks contained "**" conceal
autocmd BufEnter * syn match AsteriskBold "\*\*[^*]\+\*\*" contains=Asterisks
```

because if I write `autocmd ColorScheme * hi AsteriskBold ctermfg=Green cterm=bold` it doesn't work event after sourcing the file; don't know why...